# JavaFX tile/flow pane animation 

Tags: java, animation, javafx-2

I'm just playing around with JavaFX 2 and developing a little application for my own amusement.

From what I've seen so far, I like it, and now I'd like to play about with some of the animation and effect properties.

The app I'm designing uses a lot of images to display info, and I'd like to design a animated GUI to display the images.  The idea I've got is something like this:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LK3B7cpZlGM

Could anyone provide any information on how to achieve something similar to this? I'm guessing the layout is the flowpane, but I've no idea about how the animation works.  Is there some kind of sort algorithm in play?

Any advice or info would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several articles about animation in JavaFX:

- Video: http://medianetwork.oracle.com/video/player/1193110454001
- Tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/animations/jfxpub-animations.htm
- Ensemble [sample](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/samples/index.html) has several examples in Animation section, and "Display Shelf" example which do a simple version of animation in video.